# i try to read data folder which having files,after running code it shows exception

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

i am trying to read file,but after running the program it shows exception like,

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: (filename) (Access is denied)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
> ```

Comment: `Access is denied)` - is this a clue?

Comment: A file called `filename` seems unusual (although you may have edited out the correct name) so perhaps ensure you actually have the right file name and/or the right directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the problem precisely. The exception is common when you do not have the required privileges to access or process the files.

Check for the permissions set for a file (For different Users)
You can check the permissions in security tab by right clicking the file.